# dd: multiple input files

Tags: files, dd, cat, data

I need to concatenate chunks from two files:

if I needed concatenate whole files, I could simply do

```
cat file1 file2 > output
```

But I need to skip first 1MB from the first file, and I only want 10 MB from the second file. Sounds like a job for `dd`.

```
dd if=file1 bs=1M count=99 skip=1 of=temp1
dd if=file2 bs=1M count=10 of=temp2
cat temp1 temp2 > final_output
```

Is there a possibility to do this in one step? ie, without the need to save the intermediate results? Can I use multiple input files in `dd` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`dd` can write to stdout too.

```
( dd if=file1 bs=1M count=99 skip=1
  dd if=file2 bs=1M count=10  ) > final_output
```

Comment: This is probably the best way.  The output file isn't closed/reopened (like it is with `oflag=append conv=notrunc`), so filesystems that do delayed allocation (like XFS) are least likely to decide the file is done being written when there's still more to go.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's a good point, but as long as `dd` isn't asked to `sync`, delayed allocation shouldn't kick in immediately anyway (unless memory is tight in which case neither method will postpone allocation).

Comment: @StephenKitt: You're probably right.  I was thinking of XFS's [speculative preallocation](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_What_is_speculative_preallocation.3F), where it does need to specially detect the close/reopen access pattern (sometimes seen for log files).

Comment: In shells like `bash` and `mksh` that don't optimize out the fork for the last command in a subshell, you can make it slightly more efficient by replacing the subshell with a command group. For other shells, it shouldn't matter, and the subshell approach might even be slightly more efficient as the shell doesn't need to save and restore stdout.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can easily read multiple files in a single `dd` invocation, but you can append to build the output file in several steps:

```
dd if=file1 bs=1M count=99 skip=1 of=final_output
dd if=file2 bs=1M count=10 of=final_output oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

You need to specify both `conv=notrunc` and `oflag=append`. The first avoids truncating the output, the second starts writing from the end of the existing file.

Comment: Promising but doesn’t work on macOS Catalina `dd: unknown operand oflag`. Any workarounds to avoid using `cat`?

Comment: You could use meuh’s approach, or split it up: `dd if=file2 bs=1M count=10 >> final_output` in the second step of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Bear in mind that `dd` is a raw interface to the `read()`, `write()` and `lseek()` system call. You can only use it reliably to extract chunks of data off regular files, block devices and some character devices (like `/dev/urandom`), that is files for which `read(buf, size)` is guaranteed to return `size` as long as the end of the file is not reached.

For pipes, sockets and most character devices (like ttys), you have no such guarantee unless you do `read()`s of size 1, or use the GNU `dd` extension `iflag=fullblock`.

So either:

```
{
  gdd < file1 bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=99 skip=1
  gdd < file2 bs=1M iflag=fullblock count=10
} > final_output
```

Or:

```
M=1048576
{
  dd < file1 bs=1 count="$((99*M))" skip="$M"
  dd < file2 bs=1 count="$((10*M))"
} > final_output
```

Or with shells with builtin support for a seek operator like `ksh93`:

```
M=1048576
{
  command /opt/ast/bin/head -c "$((99*M))" < file1 <#((M))
  command /opt/ast/bin/head -c "$((10*M))" < file2
}
```

Or `zsh` (assuming your `head` supports the `-c` option here):

```
zmodload zsh/system &&
{
  sysseek 1048576 && head -c 99M &&
  head -c 10M < file2
} < file1 > final_output
```

Comment: Do you really need the quotes? Wont the result always be an integer?

Comment: @StevenPenny, leaving the expansion unquoted is asking the shell to split+glob it which wouldn't make any sense here. The split part being done on the current value of `$IFS`. That's irrespective of the content of the variable/expansion. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - in the first example, you are using `gdd` instead of `dd`. Is that a typo, or is that intentional ?

Answer (score 3):

With a **bash***ism*, and a functionally "useless use of **cat**", but  closest to the syntax the OP uses:

```
cat <(dd if=file1 bs=1M count=99 skip=1) \
    <(dd if=file2 bs=1M count=10) \
   > final_output
```

(That being said, Stephen Kitt's answer seems to be the most *efficient* possible method.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `<(...)` is a _kshism_ which both `zsh` and `bash` copied.